# Null error on button in ListView

Tags: android-studio

I am working on an alarm and I want to display a list of the alarms with two buttons (update and delete) to each container. The ListView works just fine without the two buttons but when I add the two buttons in, I get this error when the current.class tries to load:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

I am sure that I am just messing something up simple like I usually do and I was not able to find any examples that helped me figure it out. I read that RecyclerView is an advanced version of listview and works great with buttons but I would like to learn that latter so that i can get my current code working and debugged. Following is my .java and .xml for the list view. any help would be awesome, even if its just pointers to another site that has the answer. If possible I would like to get and explanation of what I did wrong so that I can learn.

current.java

```
public class current extends ListActivity {

TextView alarm_Id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.current_alarm_list);


    final AlarmRepo repo = new AlarmRepo(this);

    //get string of alarm name and id
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> AlarmList =  repo.getAlarmList();


    if(AlarmList.size()!=0) {
        ListView lv = getListView();

        Button update = (Button) lv.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
        update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
            alarm_Id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_alarm_Id);
            String alarmId = alarm_Id.getText().toString();
            Intent objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),alarmUpdate.class);
            objIndent.putExtra("alarm_Id", Integer.parseInt( alarmId));
            startActivity(objIndent);
            }
        });

        Button delete = (Button) lv.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                alarm_Id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_alarm_Id);
                String alarmId = alarm_Id.getText().toString();
                int idalarm = Integer.parseInt(alarmId);
                repo.delete(idalarm);
                startActivity(new Intent(current.this, current.class));
                finish();

            }
        });

        String[] from = { "id", "Alarm_Name" };
        int[] to = {R.id.my_alarm_Id, R.id.my_alarm_name};
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( current.this, AlarmList, R.layout.view_alarm_entry, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"No alarms!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

current_alarm_list.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.electrohaven.i_hate_ms.counterclockwise.MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    >
</ListView>
```

view_alarm_entry.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_alarm_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnUpdate"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_alarm_Id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/my_alarm_name"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnUpdate"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/my_alarm_name"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/my_alarm_name"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/btnUpdate"
    android:text="Update"
    android:focusable="false"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
    android:layout_below="@+id/my_alarm_Id"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:text="delete"
    android:focusable="false"
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two buttons are not exist at that point, they belong to a list item, not to the ListView.

My solution, but it is only a skeleton, you must fill it with your code:

Create an AlarmAdapter class:

```
public class AlarmAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
TextView alarm_Id;

private final ArrayList<Map<String, String>> alarmList;

public AlarmAdapter(final Context context, ArrayList<Map<String, String>> alarmList, String[]) {
    this.alarmList = alarmList;
}

public int getCount() {
    return alarmList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return alarmList.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_alarm_entry, null);

    View v;

    Button update = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
        update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                //onClick code
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Update: " + alarmList.get(position).toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    Button delete = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            //onClick code
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Delete: " + alarmList.get(position).toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    return itemView;
}
```

Put this to the onCreate function in the activity:

```
    if(AlarmList.size()!=0) {
        String[] from = { "id", "Alarm_Name" };
        int[] to = {R.id.my_alarm_Id, R.id.my_alarm_name};

        AlarmAdapter adapter = new AlarmAdapter( getApplicationContext(), AlarmList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"No alarms!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```